# Database returned to CIRCULAR mode but logs are still being archived to old location

Tags: db2, transaction-log, logs, db2-luw, archive

my DB2 database (v 9.7) is in Circular mode.

```
Current Logging Type:Circular

(USEREXIT) = OFF
(LOGRETAIN) = OFF
(LOGARCHMETH1) = OFF
(LOGARCHMETH2) = OFF
(LOGPRIMARY) = 10
(LOGSECOND) = 10
Path to log files: /home/ctginst1/ctginst1/NODE0000/SQL00001/SQLOGDIR/
```

I had old archive location `/opt/IBM/archive`
and now my hard disk space is full 100% because I have over 500 logs in that location which I cannot find that is defined somewhere.

What is going on?Why archive logs keep coming to old archive log location?

This is really big problem for us I will be thankful for any help

Comment: Are you sure that circular took affect? Did you force everyone off the DB and deactivate it?

Comment: Hi Chris, you  mean to run db2 force application all, db2stop, and db2start and it should take affect? Please confirm me  I did not do that. I did however do the offline backup recently I will check if logs are still coming after some time

Comment: Simply deactivating the database (which would have happened with an offline backup) will cause the change to go into effect.

Comment: Thank you Chris and Ian. I suppose I can delete all those old archive logs now when I have offline backup?? Please confirm

Comment: Once you have an offline backup, you should be on circular logging. So yes, you can delete those archived logs. If your paranoid (and a good DBA should be), take a file system backup before you delete the logs. Then you have them just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Run `GET DB CFG` with the `SHOW DETAIL` option, which will reveal any settings that are delayed (not yet active). Any difference between the "Current" and "Delayed" value indicates a DB CFG change that was made after the database was last activated.

If the old path isn't showing up in any of the settings in the "Current" column of the database config, then examine the logging settings of other local databases on the system (and in other local instances if any exist) to see if they're the culprit.

It also wouldn't hurt to take a look at the crontab schedules on the server to see if a cron job is responsible for copying the files to an inappropriate path.

Answer (score -1):

[image]
this how we need to update the new active log path. once it is done we need to restart db2 and activate db , then it will change to newlog path value to your path to log files. this activity requires minimal down time.

after restart it will change to like below

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).